# TypeScript module Augmentation

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have extension for observable. It was working perfectly fine but now I've updated to angular 6 with typescript 2.7.2.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BaseComponent } from './base-component';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Subscribable } from 'rxjs';

declare module 'rxjs/Observable' {
    export interface Observable<T> {
        safeSubscribe<T>(this: Observable<T>, component: BaseComponent,
            next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: T) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
    }
}


export function safeSubscribe<T>(this: Observable<T>, component: BaseComponent,
    next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: T) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription {
    let sub = this.subscribe(next, error, complete);
    component.markForSafeDelete(sub);
    return sub;
}

Observable.prototype.safeSubscribe = safeSubscribe;
```

And this code is not working

1. 'Observable' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
2. Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When merging declarations, the specified module path must exactly match the path to the actual module.

With RxJS version 6, you will need to change your module declaration, as the internal structure has changed. From memory, it should be:

```
declare module 'rxjs/internal/Observable' {
    export interface Observable<T> {
        safeSubscribe<T>(this: Observable<T>, component: BaseComponent,
            next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: T) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
    }
}
```

For an example, see [one of the patching imports](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.1.0/compat/add/operator/audit.ts) in `rxjs-compat`.

Comment: Thank you. Ohh... I wasted whole day yesterday, i've seen that its in internal but missed that.

Comment: In the past, declaration merging has wasted a lot of my time, too. I feel your pain.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat Did you have any issues with it saying "safeSubscribe() is not a function"? We're trying to do something similar as you are. It compiles but at runtime it says that it's not a function.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I'm assuming you're using this to do something like ... foo.pipe(...).safeSubscribe(...) ? We're trying something similar above and that's where it tells me it's not a function

Comment: Yes, you can check in my blog, but there is still old source code https://www.bilyachat.com/blog/angular-automatically-unsubscribe-from