# angular rxjs 6 safeSubscribe is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

the following is an extension to observable to provide a `safeSubscribe` method that results in a subscription that each component's `onDestroy` method automatically unsubscribes.

```
// once _takeUntilDestroy$ on target emits, the subscription gets canceled
export function safeSubscribe<T>(target: any,
                                 next?: (value: T) => void,
                                 error?: (error: T) => void,
                                 complete?: () => void): Subscription {
  target._takeUntilDestroy$ = target._takeUntilDestroy$ || new Subject(); // our kill-switch for the subscription being defined
  return this.pipe(
    takeUntil(target._takeUntilDestroy$.asObservable()) // takeUntil enables the kill-switch
  ).subscribe(next, error, complete);
}

/****  add safeSubscribe to Observable ****/
(Observable as any).prototype.safeSubscribe = safeSubscribe;
declare module 'rxjs/internal/Observable' { // rxjs5 would be rxjs/Observable
 export interface Observable<T> {
    safeSubscribe: typeof safeSubscribe;
  }
}
```

I have taken the merge declaration part from [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321926/typescript-module-augmentation/50322026#50322026).

This implementation works perfectly when subscribing to Angular HTTPClient requests, but it fails when I try to `safeSubscribe` to observables created using factory methods like `fromEvent`:

```
fromEvent(this.fileInput.nativeElement, 'change').safeSubscribe<any>(this, (x) => { console.log(x); });
```

yielding a `safeSubscribe is not a function` error.

Am I extending Observable in the wrong way?

**Output of npm list rxjs**

```
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.6.3
| +-- @angular-devkit/architect@0.6.3
| | `-- rxjs@6.2.0  deduped
| +-- @angular-devkit/core@0.6.3
| | `-- rxjs@6.2.0  deduped
| `-- rxjs@6.2.0  deduped
+-- @angular/cli@6.0.3
| +-- @angular-devkit/schematics@0.6.3
| | `-- rxjs@6.2.0  deduped
| +-- @schematics/update@0.6.3
| | `-- rxjs@6.2.0  deduped
| `-- rxjs@6.2.0  deduped
`-- rxjs@6.2.0
```

Comment: @cartant I'm tagging you as I figured out the declaration merging thanks to your answer, hoping that you experienced this error already

Comment: There's nothing special about the factory methods. The most likely explanation is that there are multiple installations of RxJS and one is patched and the other is not. Run `npm list rxjs` to see what's installed in `node_modules`.

Comment: BTW, your signature should include `this`, like this: `safeSubscribe<T>(this: Observable<T>, target: any, ...`

Comment: @cartman thx, I will check this out tomorrow when I'm back at the office

Comment: @cartant from npm list rxjs I'd say that I have only one install. Maybe rxjs-compat is to blame, gonna try removing it now. Regarding the method signature, I call my implementation like anObservable.safeSubscribe(this, next, error, complete) as I want the current component. I don't get the reason for passing an observable as argument again

Comment: If you are adding it to the prototype, it should include a `this` parameter. The `this` isn't passed; it's included in the signature to indicate the type of the `this` context when called. Check the TypeScript docs for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Hi @cartant, thanks for the pointer to `this`. Sadly I stil can't get that to work with observables created with `from`

Comment: I would encourage you to create a smaller reproduction of the problem, as - aside from the signature - you don't appear to be doing anything wrong.

Comment: You are right, the way I'm asking for help now is not structured at all. I'll make a stackblitz tonight and update my question.